# jQuery SlideUp/SlideDown madness

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slidedown, slideup

I'm a noob at query and trying to make one, obviously simple thing to happen. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrkrabs/wfUu5/3/) that i made. As you see i have 3 buttons: Close (closes all open div's) AZ and AR. When i click AZ it slides down, when i click AR (assume the AZ is still open) it slides AZ Up and Slides AR down so there's only 1 div open at a time. However, if I click on opened div it slides Up and Slides Down again. What I want to do is when the div is open (i.e. slided Down) and I click on it it should not slideUp->Down again. In other words, if the div is open then nothing should happen when i click on it again as I have a Close button for that.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me

http://jsfiddle.net/wfUu5/4/

not saying it's the ideal solution (the whole code could be written better), but it fixes your problem using your code

Comment: great, i knew it was easy! Thank you.

Comment: you're right, it works good, but let's say i have 20 not 2 div's i need to slide, it's going to be huge amount of code then. Is there a way to remove class 'active' on all elements, instead of specifying #az, #ar like in here $('#az, #ar').removeClass('active'); ?

Comment: add a common class to them, ie `slide-togglers` and then simply do `$('.slide-togglers').removeClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

If you got the possibility to clean that code a bit I made a easy way to make it more dynamic: http://jsfiddle.net/wfUu5/5/

thats how I would have solved it.

and if you wanted a ".selected" class on your tds: http://jsfiddle.net/wfUu5/6/

Comment: this is great, thank you, will try to optimize my code and give it a try.